# Loading GeoJSON into QGIS

Tags: qgis, geojson

I am a beginner with QGIS. I am trying to learn it through lynda.com. I have tried downloading the nanaimo crime map in GeoJSON format, but I get a message saying that the data source is invalid.

I am bemused at to what I do as I am following the instructions to the letter.

[image: pick of QGIS]

Answer (score 15):

The JSON you are using is just simple JSON not GeoJSON. The main difference is that the GeoJSON contains a geometry object you can read more about [here](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html) in the GeoJSON spec.

You can however convert your JSON to a CSV file and load it into QGIS that way.

1. Go to a site like [this one](http://www.convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm) and put in the URL to your JSON. I plugged in "http://www.nanaimo.ca/crimereporting/api/incidents" into the "Option 2 - Enter URL".
2. Convert the JSON to a CSV file on that site and download it to your machine.
3. Then in QGIS add a delimited text layer the button is circled below (im using QGIS version 2.14.3).
   [image]
4. Load the CSV file you created and downloaded from that website, make sure in the dialog that you have set the file format as "CSV", the x-field to "Long" and the y-field to "Lat". Use the image below for reference.
   [image]
5. Once you load the layer it should pop up in your map, you may get a warning saying that no CRS was defined and it is going to assume EPSG:4326. Final output should look like below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Reading the documentation here http://www.nanaimo.ca/crimereporting/help
it seems you can construct a query url as the following and this will return the GeoJSON you are looking for

http://www.nanaimo.ca/crimereporting/api/incidents.geojson