# Using Google BigQuery GIS table as a data source to QGIS

Tags: qgis, big-data, google-cloud

Google BigQuery recently added GIS functionality (still in beta), see [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/gis-intro).

I have a dataset in BigQuery that I would like to use as a data source in QGIS - much the same way as I would do with a normal PostGIS database or a CSV file.

Is there a way to do this?

I guess I could export the data from bigquery into a PostGIS instance in GCS, and then I would be able to load it into QGIS. But that doesn't feel like the right way to do it.

Size of data is not a concern, and I'm using QGIS 3.4.2 (Madeira).

Comment: What do you think about [exporting as GeoJSON](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/gis-data#exporting_spatial_data) and then [importing in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/199403/loading-geojson-into-qgis)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that's one possibility but it has the problem that if I update my data I will have to export and import it again. Ideally, I would like to avoid this - same way as I would if I was using a postGIS db

Comment: You are welcome, sorry for a poor suggestion. I am not an expert in this domain, so probably let's wait for a better hint/answer. Maybe you have to develop an add-on to let data update in PostGIS after the GeoJSON would be automatically created, e.g. [Import GeoJSON into PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172092/import-geojson-into-postgis)

Comment: What I can think is creating a connection with R using the libraries bigqueryR and RQGIS3, everything in a single script; otherwise you should program a plugin in QGIS. @JoãoCoelho

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll keep that in mind if I can't find a more straightforward solution. I'll also look into what it takes to create a plugin for QGIS - if you have any thoughts or tips on that feel free to share them :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were two solutions people described using in BQGIS group,

- https://groups.google.com/d/topic/bq-gis-feedback/4lQ60053N0I/discussion

One is import plugin for QGIS,

- https://github.com/unacast/bigquerylayers

Another is foreign data wrapper for PostgreSQL, then using Postgre layers in QGIS:

- https://github.com/gabfl/bigquery_fdw

Comment: Unacast's plugin works wonderfully, thank you